# Create GenericService Bean with FactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

I create Beans for my Generic Service with FactoryBean.

Service:

```
public abstract class SimpleServiceImpl<T extends IdEntity>
        implements SimpleService<T> {

    @Autowired
    SimpleRepository<T> entitiesRepository;

    ...
```

Factory:

```
@Component
public class ServiceFactoryBean<E extends IdEntity> extends ServiceAbstractFactoryBean<E> {

        @Override
        protected SimpleServiceImpl<E> doCreateInstance() {
            return new SimpleServiceImpl<E>() { };
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getObjectType() {
            return SimpleService.class;
        }
    }
```

if I create bean with this factory then `SimpleRepository<T> entitiesRepository;` eqally `SimpleRepostirory<IdEntity>` not `T` class, what I doing wrong?

Example use Factory:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController extends SimpleController<User> {
    @Autowired
    public UserController(ServiceFactoryBean<User> serviceFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        super(serviceFactoryBean.getObject());
    }
}
```

If I replace `T` to `User` in `ServiceFactoryBean` , it work

```
@Component
public class ServiceFactoryBean<> extends ServiceAbstractFactoryBean<User> {

    @Override
    protected SimpleServiceImpl<User> doCreateInstance() {
        return new SimpleServiceImpl<User>() { };

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SimpleService.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess, this solution comes from you previous question, where you don't want create multiple factories manually. Honestly, I can't find another way than create them manually.

Comment: I can create bean manually without factory `@Bean
    public SimpleService<Author> authorService() { return new SimpleServiceImpl<Author>() { }; }`, but I want create beans with one factory. thx for answer

Comment: You should not inject a factory bean, it is used to produce a bean, not to be itself used for retrieving the object explicitely.